# Identify the points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f'_n(x)=f'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Identify the points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f'_n(x)=f'(x)$ for

$$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+nx^2}.$$

My attempt: I showed in an earlier part of this problem that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f(x)=0$, so we want to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f'_n(x)=f'(x)=0$.

We can see that

$$f_n'(x)=\frac{1-nx^2}{(1+nx^2)^2},$$

which appears to converge to $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity for a fixed $x$. Is this enough?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's enaugh, except that for $x=0$ it doesn't work ;)